# Add fields to NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsmutableurlrequest

How would I add key value pairs to the body of a NSMutableURLRequest? I know I could use something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/upload/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *bodyContents = @"fileName=";
[bodyContents stringByAppendingString:fileName];
[bodyContents stringByAppendingString:@"&"];
[bodyContents stringByAppendingString:@"deviceName="];
[bodyContents stringByAppendingString:deviceName];
[bodyContents stringByAppendingString:@"fileContents="];
[bodyContents stringByAppendingString:fileContents];
```

But that seems like a lot of hassle, especially if I get to where I need to submit a lot of values in a request. I would hope apple would provide a method like `[request addBodyField:@"fileName":fileName]` or something equally useful, but I haven't been able to find one in the documentation. Is there one I'm missing or should I just stick to appending strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of good answers here.  Here's what I do: I built a parameter class that takes care of the pairing syntax as well as url encoding.

```
#import "NSString+URLEncoding.h"

@interface UrlParameter ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *pair;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *encodedPair;

@end

@implementation UrlParameter

@synthesize pair = _pair;
@synthesize encodedPair = _encodedPair;


+ (UrlParameter *)withName:(NSString *)name value:(NSString *)value {

    UrlParameter *answer = [[UrlParameter alloc] init];
    answer.pair = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", name, value];
    answer.encodedPair = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", [name urlEncode], [value urlEncode]];

    return answer;  // autorelease if non-ARC
}

@end
```

This relies on this NSString category method that I cobbled out of a couple posts.  (Also ARC-ready):

```
@implementation NSString (URLEncoding)

- (NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(CFStringEncoding)encoding {

    return CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                               (__bridge CFStringRef)self,
                                                               NULL,
                                                               CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"),
                                                               encoding));
}

- (NSString *)urlEncode {
    return [self urlEncodeUsingEncoding:kCFStringEncodingUTF8];
}

@end
```

I also subclass the URL request and give it mutable array of parameters, then, before it starts, it does this:

```
// in the interface
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *parameters;

- (void)prepareParameters {

    NSMutableString *encodedParameterPairs = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:256];

    int position = 1;
    for (UrlParameter *requestParameter in self.parameters) {
        [encodedParameterPairs appendString:[requestParameter encodedPair]];
        if (position < [self.parameters count]) [encodedParameterPairs appendString:@"&"];
        position++;
    }

    if ([[self HTTPMethod] isEqualToString:@"GET"] || [[self HTTPMethod] isEqualToString:@"DELETE"]) {

        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", [self URLString], encodedParameterPairs];
        [self setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    } else {

        // POST, PUT
        NSData *postData = [encodedParameterPairs dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        [self setHTTPBody:postData];
        [self setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [self setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    }
}
```

Comment: essentially what I wound up doing too

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `stringByAppendingString` doesn't modify the string in place, but returns a new string that contains the result. However, you are not assigning the result of `stringByAppendingString` to any variable, and `bodyContents` remains unchanged.

To solve that, you can either use `stringWithFormat`:

```
NSString *bodyContents = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fileName=%@&deviceName=%@fileContents=%@", fileName, deviceName, fileContents];
```

Or declare `stringWithFormat` as a mutable string and use the method `appendString`:

```
NSMutableString *bodyContents = @"fileName=";
[bodyContents appendString:fileName];
[bodyContents appendString:@"&"];
// ...
```

Or assign the result of `stringWithFormat` to `bodyContents` at every call:

```
NSString *bodyContents = @"fileName=";
bodyContents = [bodyContents stringByAppendingString:fileName];
bodyContents = [bodyContents stringByAppendingString:@"&"];
// ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend +stringWithFormat.

EDIT: Like so:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/upload/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *bodyContents = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fileName=%@%@%@%@%@%@",fileName, @"&",@"deviceName=",deviceName,@"fileContents=",fileContents];
```

I have not had to use any NSMutableRequests, but if you need string literals (\n for newline \t for tab), or punctuation, just put them where necessary between each %@.

Comment: I would say `[request setValue:@"string" forHTTPHeaderField:@"string"];`, but I don't believe that is what you are trying to accomplish....

Comment: @CodaFi - You can simplify the line `NSString *bodyContents = [NSString stringWithFormat...` even more, because there are actually only three parameters. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell. **Create string:**

```
NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fileName=%@&deviceName=%@&fileContents=@%", fileName, deviceName, fileContents];
```

**Format to NSData:**

```
NSData *body = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**Add body to request:**

```
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

**NOTE:** the format of `bodyString` depends on POST format of your request: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`. If you use `multipart/form-data` - this format possibly will not be acceptable by server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you'll have to use a string.

By the way, your string isn't an NSMutableString, so those `stringByAppendingString:` methods won't actually do anything unless you also have `bodyContents = [bodyContents string...`

`stringWithFormat` is the best way:

```
NSString *bodyContents = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fileName:%@&deviceName=%@&fileContents=%@", fileName, deviceName, fileContents"];
```

Alternatively, you could have an NSArray of keys and an NSDictionary (to hold the values) which is based off that key. Then simply loop through the NSArray and create the string.